# Django REST Framework: sending an image from android

Tags: android, python, django, image

I'm trying to send an image through my Android application to Django, where it will make the analysis of that image (with python code). I'm sending the image in Base64, but when I receive it, the format gets all messed up. How can I send the image correctly, and is this the right format?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField)

combined with a code like that:

`class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the UPloadedImage Model
    Provides the pk, image, thumbnail, title and description
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedImage
        fields = ('pk', 'image', 'thumbnail', 'title', 'description', )
        read_only_fields = ('thumbnail',)`